# What is [@requested = 1] in a meta tag?

Tags: html, http-headers, request, keyword, meta-key

I found a snippet of code on a website that i have never seem before. I searched and couldn't find an answer for it, and even tried contacting the webmaster... So lets see if someone here can. It is a meta tag that says "seo/seo[@requested = 1]/metakeys

```
<meta name="keywords" content="seo/seo[@requested = 1]/metadescription">
<meta name="keywords" content="seo/seo[@requested = 1]/metakeys">
```

Comment: It's nothing official in a spec or seo related. Probably a botched template or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`seo/seo[@requested = 1]/metakeys` is an XPath query. XPath is a query language designed to extract information from XML documents.

Presumably, the value for that attribute is supposed fetched from an XML document when the page is generated, but a bug causes the XPath to be included in the (X)HTML instead of the results of the query.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense that it wouldn't populate then, because there isn't an xml file on the page. It is [bilderbergmeetings.org](http://www.bliderbergmeetings.org/) if you want to see it.

Comment: The XML file would be as hidden as the script that generated the file itself. You would never see it. It has nothing to do with what's on the page. The XPath was meant to be processed by the script generating the HTML page.